# Why Lubuntu 18.04 calls Amazon servers? (motd.ubuntu.com)

Tags: lubuntu, privacy, motd

In wireshark logs I found that my Lubuntu 18.04 calls [Amazon servers](http://ip-api.org/#54.194.229.79). See this log:

```
17  192.168.1.1 192.168.1.13    DNS 118 Standard query response 0x0e33 A motd.ubuntu.com A 54.194.229.79 A 52.18.210.215 OPT
18  192.168.1.1 192.168.1.13    DNS 142 Standard query response 0xebef AAAA motd.ubuntu.com AAAA 2a05:d018:91c:3200:4a81:cf9a:267b:97df AAAA 2a05:d018:91c:3200:5869:6d03:bf3a:f619 OPT
19  192.168.1.13    54.194.229.79   TCP 74  50656  >  443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=4010357077 TSecr=0 WS=128
20  54.194.229.79   192.168.1.13    TCP 74  443  >  50656 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=26847 Len=0 MSS=1380 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2116889653 TSecr=4010357077 WS=128
21  192.168.1.13    54.194.229.79   TCP 66  50656  >  443 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=29312 Len=0 TSval=4010357137 TSecr=2116889653
22  192.168.1.13    54.194.229.79   TLSv1.2 284 Client Hello
```

It downloads some message of the day (MOTD). What is it and how to disable this "feature"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a look in `/etc/update-motd.d/` you will see the configuration that is responsible for updating motd with information.

It's the `50-motd-news`-file that is responsible for fetching news from motd.ubuntu.com (which is controlled by Ubuntu, but hosted in AWS, which is why whois shows Amazon).

Simply remove the `50-motd-news`-file, and it will stop checking for news for motd.

You can also remove the `update-motd` package if you desire. `sudo apt remove update-motd` will disable all automatic motd updates, including update and reboot notifications.

In addition, you should change `ENABLED=1` to `ENABLED=0` in `/etc/default/motd-news`.

## How I found this

I can add how I figured out this. I did a `grep -r 'motd.ubuntu.com' /etc/ 2>/dev/null`. This showed the two files mentioned above.

A `apt-cache search update-motd` confirmed that this was a package, and `man update-motd` explained how it works:

> Executable scripts in /etc/update-motd.d/* are executed by pam_motd(8) as the root user at each login, and this information  is  concatenated in  /run/motd.dynamic.  The order of script execution is determined by the run-parts(8) --lsbsysinit option  (basically  alphabetical  order, with a few caveats).

Thus, removing any individual scripts will not be harmful. You can even add your own if you want.